# Displaying an image with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

***Solved:*** *The answer was to update all of the nuget packages and target a newer version of Android. Now images loads as expected. I'm not happy with this as I was using exactly the code that Xamarin provided and targeting newer versions has deprecated some of the items the code relys on. Initial version was Xamarin.Forms v23 and I updated to V25*

I have a brand new Xamarin forms project with a simple view in which I'm trying to display an image. I've tried several ways of getting an image to display and I am not having any luck at all.

I'm using `<image>` and I have also tried FFImageLoader control as well.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

        <ff:CachedImage Source="https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" />

        <Button x:Name="btn" Text="Image" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />

        <Frame OutlineColor="Red">
            <Image x:Name="StupidImage" Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"  Aspect="Fill" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"   />
        </Frame>

        </StackLayout>
```

This is the current view. I've also set the Source directly to a value with no result.

I'm able to get a stream for the image. I'm able to read all of the bytes from the stream. I built a debug visualizer to display the bytes as an image. Getting the image from a source is not a problem. Getting the image control(s) to display the image is a problem.

I tried binding with a view model. When that failed, I tried that directly setting the source

```
StupidImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => result.Stream);
```

I also made a copy of the bytes and tried

```
StupidImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
```

I've tried `ImageSource.FromFile()` and `.FromUri`. I tried adding an image to the project as a resource. Each try was the same, the resource was read and the bytes were available, but the image control just doesn't display it.

I thought maybe it was a size problem, so I set the size of the control. Nothing. I thought maybe it was a resolution problem, so I used a smaller image. I tried several different images of varying quality.

Then I gave up on the image control and I got the FFImageLoading nuget package and gave it a direct url to an image. Same example that FFImageLoading examples used. Still no image.

I tried the emulator and I tried 2 different physical devices. Same result.

I also tried setting an image on a button using `btn.Image = "whatever.jpg"` with the same result.

This is the result every time. I'm lost. How do I get images to display?

**EDIT:**
I did get this to work, but only on the emulator

```
<Image x:Name="StupidImage" Source="https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg" />
```

and same for

```
StupidImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg"));
```

**EDIT 2 - Clarification**

My goal is to allow the user to select a photo from the device and then display a preview of it.

[image]

Comment: Put your image in content view and try its coming or not

Comment: Did you try it on another platforms except Android? Here is the official documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Downloading_Images Try to disable caching ...

Comment: @EvZ I am trying to load a file from the device, not a url. I did try the uri example in the link your provided and i did get it working (on the emulator at least), but still cannot get it to work with a stream or file

Comment: Where did you place that image file ? PCL or Android project?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use images in you app you can load them into your Shared Project, like

[image: Embedded resource]

Make sure you change the **Build Action** to **Embedded resource**

Then in your code

```
image.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("App5.Images.useravatar.png");
```

Note the Resource name.

And XAML

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Image x:Name="image" WidthRequest="50"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: The goal is to allow the user to select an image from their device, and then display a preview of it.

Comment: Have you seen this plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Comment: I had not seen that, but looking at it, I might know what my issue is. I've read that when you take a photo during the image selection process, you have to save a copy of it and then reference the copy, maybe I need to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few things you can take off the list:

[x] Adding a image from Visual studio :

1. Right click on the correct folder
2. select Add >> New File ...
   NB: you have to add it with visual studio and not just throw it in the folder. Visual studio needs to know about it

[x] When Adding the image is it in the correct place :

- For android:  it has to be in

`ProjectName.Driod.Resources.drawable` folder

- For ios: it has to be in

`ProjectName.iOS.Resources` folder

[x] Naming Convention

- Its always best to use **.png** , **all lowercase** , **no spaces** or special char on both android and ios
- with ios you normally get 3 images of the same image with the following namting convention

  - theman.png
  - theman@2x.png
  - theman@3x.png
- They are all the same image just different sizes

[x] Showing it in xaml :

```
   <StackLayout>
     <Image Source="thedog.png" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" />
   </StackLayout>
```

- In your example you used a frame , how about a stacklayout ? a frame has more requirements.
- for MVVM you can change Source with the following , dont forget that twoway :)

  - `Source="{Binding Thumbnail, Mode=TwoWay}"`

**NB** This is VERY basic explanations

Answer (score 2):

You can try implementing the [CrossMedia Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin).

Then in your button clicked code section, put the following:

```
        Button_Clicked.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
        {

            if ( !CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported )
            {
                DisplayAlert("Error message here", "More message", "OK");
                return;
            }

            var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
            {
                PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium
            });


            if (file == null)
                return;

            image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                file.Dispose();
                return stream;
            });
        };
```

Once the button is clicked, the gallery/directory will be displayed. You can choose the photo you want. Once you hit OK the image will be displayed in the Image control/tag. I'm not sure if this is the solution you are looking for. Hopes it gets you on the right direction.

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work, but have been unsuccessful. Issues with versioning have held me back.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help I'll add some code, one of the surprising things about Xamarin forms and Android and using a memory stream.. is that the device density multiplier is still applied even if you aren't using a resource(If I am remembering correctly) so I would imagine if you are looking at the ADB interface you will see memory issues which is why you cant display an image... I solved this previously via sampling

The way I solved it was creating a new Image subclass -ResourceImage,

```
public class ResourceImage :Image
{
    public enum SourceTypes{

        Database,

        File,

        Function,
    }

    private bool _LoadAct = false;

    public bool LoadAct { get{

            return _LoadAct;

        }



        set{ _LoadAct = value; OnPropertyChanged ("LoadAct");



        }

    }

    public Func<Stream> Func{ get; set; }

    public SourceTypes SourceType{ get; set;}

    public string ResName{ get; set;}

    public ResourceImage ()

    {

    }



    public ResourceImage (string name)

    {
        ResName = name;

    }



    public ResourceImage(Func<Stream> func){

        SourceType = SourceTypes.Function;

        Func = func;

    }

}
```

then in the Android Renderer : I did the following

```
    public class ResourceImageRenderer : ImageRenderer

{

    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)

    {

        base.OnElementChanged (e);



        if (e.OldElement == null) 

        {

            var el = (ResourceImage)Element;

            if (el.SourceType == ResourceImage.SourceTypes.Database) {

                //Ignore for now

            } else if (el.SourceType == ResourceImage.SourceTypes.File) {

                using (global::Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options options = new global::Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options ()) {

                    options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    options.InSampleSize = 1;//calculateInSampleSize (options, outS.X / 4, outS.Y / 4);

                    var gd = Context.Resources.GetIdentifier (el.ResName.Split (new char[]{ '.' }) [0], "drawable", Context.PackageName);

                    using (global::Android.Graphics.Rect rt = new global::Android.Graphics.Rect (0, 0, 0, 0)) {

                        var bitmap = global::Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource (Context.Resources, gd, options);//DecodeStream (ms, rt, options);

                        bitmap.Density = global::Android.Graphics.Bitmap.DensityNone;

                        Control.SetImageDrawable (new global::Android.Graphics.Drawables.BitmapDrawable (bitmap));

                    }

                }

            } else if (el.SourceType == ResourceImage.SourceTypes.Function) {



                new Task (() => {


                    var ms = el.Func();

                    if(ms == null)return;

global::Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options options = new global::Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options ();



                        options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;



                        options.InSampleSize = 2;//calculateInSampleSize (options, outS.X / 4, outS.Y / 4);

                        ms.Position = 0;
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>{

                            using (global::Android.Graphics.Rect rt = new global::Android.Graphics.Rect (0, 0, 0, 0)) {



                                try{

                                    var bitmap = global::Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeStream (ms, rt, options);

                                    bitmap.Density = global::Android.Graphics.Bitmap.DensityNone;

                                    Control.SetImageDrawable (new global::Android.Graphics.Drawables.BitmapDrawable (bitmap));

                                }catch(Exception  eee){


                                }

                        }

                        });




                }).Start(); 

            }

        }       

    }
```

Looking back at the code(haven't touched it in years.) there are plenty of places for improvement, I had to add the sampling to solve the same issue , users were selecting images to display in a messaging app and it worked perfectly on iOS just never displayed on Android

Comment: FFImageLoading plugin handles this issue https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading

Answer (score 0):

This is how I allow a user to select an image and then display it on a page.

I call my image service Select Image method passing in a callback method

```
 await _imageService.SelectImage(ImageSelected);
```

This is my SelectImage method. There is some permission checking at the start. It uses the Media Plugin to display the gallery and allow the user to select an image.

```
public async Task SelectImage(Action<MediaFile> imageAction)
{
    var allowed = await _permissionService.CheckOrRequestStoragePermission();
    if (!allowed) return;

    if (!_media.IsPickPhotoSupported)
    {
        throw new GalleryUnavailableException("Gallery unavailable");
    }

    var file = await _media.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
    {
        PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small,
        CompressionQuality = 92
    });

    imageAction(file);
}
```

It returns a MediaFile

Here is the Image Selected callback method

```
private void ImageSelected(MediaFile image)
{
    if (image == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    ChosenImage = new IncidentImage
    {
        ImageBytes = image.ToByteArray()
    };
}
```

ChosenImage is a Property in my view model

```
public IncidentImage ChosenImage {get; set;}
```

I use PropertyChanged.Fody to trigger property changed notifications but you can also use INotifyPropertyChanged.

And IncidentImage is a class I use to both store and display images

```
public class IncidentImage
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int IncidentDetailsId { get; set; }

    public byte[] ImageBytes { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            ImageSource retval = null;
            try
            {
                if (ImageBytes != null)
                {
                    retval = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(ImageBytes));
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }
            return retval;
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the XAML

```
<Image Source="{Binding ChosenImage.ImageSource}"
       Aspect="AspectFit"/>
```