# Using SVG images in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, svg, xamarin.forms

I'm using the nugget package `SVG.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions`, I have copied the XAML below from a simple example but cannot get the SVG to show.

The image is in an 'images' folder within the 'TestApp' application and it's build action is 'Embedded Resource'. `SvgAssebly` is bound to the public assembly below in the viewModel.

All I get is a blank screen with the title text at the top.
Can anyone see anything obviously wrong?

```
public Assembly SvgAssembly
{
       get { return typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="TestApp.MainPage" 
             xmlns:artina="clr-namespace:UXDivers.Artina.Shared;assembly=UXDivers.Artina.Shared" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp;assembly=TestApp" Title="{ artina:Translate PageTitle}" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BasePageColor}"
             xmlns:abstractions="clr-namespace:SVG.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=SVG.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions">

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout>
            <abstractions:SvgImage
                SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly }"
                SvgPath="TestApp.images.brand.svg"
                Width="200"
                Height="200" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: what device platform are you focusing on ?

Answer (score 1):

Just a note :

1. remove the spacing from your binding :

   SvgAssembly="{Binding SvgAssembly }"
2. You should be referencing the image like this :

   SvgPath="brand.SVG"

You need to make sure you are referencing the image correctly :
my answer from another question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47336742/displaying-an-image-with-xamarin-forms/47474120#answer-47474120)

Answer (score 0):

Try using FFImageLoading as it has an option to use SVG images. It also has the option to cache images on the user's device. Find the documentation below:

https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API